# Is there any vertex-transitive non-Cayley graph with 24 vertices and valency 5?

Tags: graph-theory

I know that, by D. McKay and C. E. Praeger papers" Vertex-transitive graphs which are not Cayley graphs I", there exist 112 non-Cayley vertex-transitive graph with 24 vertices. 
Is there any such graph of valency 5? Which graph is the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is one, see [this paper](https://cs.anu.edu.au/people/Brendan.McKay/papers/Transitive26.pdf).

You can fetch it from [Gordon Royle's collection](http://staffhome.ecm.uwa.edu.au/~00013890/remote/trans/index.html).

Comment: Dear Prof. McKay, thank you for your answer. I need the adjacency of vertices of this unique graph. I want to compute the automorphism group of this graph. Is the graph a well-know graph?

Comment: You can get the graph from this [file](http://staffhome.ecm.uwa.edu.au/~00013890/remote/trans/noncay24.g6.gz). You can use software, e.g. [sagemath](https://cloud.sagemath.com/), to find out the automorphism group and the adjacency lists of the graph.